# How to use the Stellar SDK API Reference?

Tags: stellar-sdk, horizon, trustline

I am trying to understand how the API reference is meant to be used.

For example I want to see how to set up a trust line for an account using the changeTrust() operation.

I went to the API reference here: https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.changeTrust

But I can't understand how to use this. There's no examples of the changeTrust() function called or source code implementations.

I am not sure how to use the reference and documentation and would appreciate any help if somebody could break down how things like this:
[image: this] should be interpreted.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK reference documentation is built automatically from the sources using  JS Doc format parser, so it doesn't contain the detailed information and usage examples, only methods descriptions extracted from JS Doc comments.

You'll find practical use cases with line-by-line comments [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html).

Comment: In that case do you happen to know how the documents or guides should be used to find out how a change trust operation would be performed when creating an account?